# Why won't my class variables get initialized by my _construct function?

Tags: php

I'm learning to use the _construct function for initializing classes... and I seemed to be on the right path, but then at debug the class variables return empty.

Here's the code:

Class Access.php

```
class Access {
    var $username='';
    var $password='';
    var $result=false;
    var $error='';


    /** OBJECT CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION / CREATES ACCESS OBJECT**/
    public function _construct($username, $password) {

        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;

    }
}
```

and my test code:

```
include "Access.php";

$un = 'FakeUN';
$pw = 'FakePW';

$a = new Access($un,$pw);

echo $a->username;
echo $a->password;
```

this prints nothing on the screen; the class variables were not initialized.

If you could let me know what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the constructor method is `__construct`. All magic methods begin with **two** underscores.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write 2x `_`!

You just forgot to write 2 underscores

So write:

```
public function __construct($username, $password) {
    //do something

}
```